# How do I retrieve data from SQLite to VB6?

Tags: sqlite, vb6, odbc, ado

I am using SQLite3 ODBC Driver as my connection string,

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
 Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=test.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"

conn.Open

rs.Open "select * from Artists", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
MsgBox rs.Fields(0)
```

Comment: i always received this error: Run-time error '-2147217887 (800e21)': ODBC driver does not support the requested properties

Comment: If the error says " ODBC driver does not support the requested properties" I guess that the ODBC driver does not support the requested properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer here for the connection string properties: 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

You should also specify the version (3 or 2).

Edit: try to remove: LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0
And add the version: version=3
If it works, try to add a property at a time until it won't work anymore, to identify the broken property.

Comment: i've already browse that site, was my connection string incorrect? please help., i appreciate your reply.

Comment: yeah it works! and i also test each property until it becomes: "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=test.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;version=3;"
but i works fine, im so confuse on what happen to this connection string.

Comment: `version=3` is surely ignored. You are using `SQLite*3* ODBC Driver` so the version is part of the driver name. Use full path name for `Database` or risk random failures depending on your current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

These are available connect string options for `SQLite3 ODBC Driver`

```
Description=
Database=<<file_name>
Timeout=
StepAPI=0
SyncPragma=
NoTXN=0
ShortNames=0
LongNames=0
NoCreat=0
NoWCHAR=0
FKSupport=0
LoadExt=
```

I just created a system DSN and looked in registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\<<my_dsn_here>>`